# Storing API in local array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to store data from an API into an array using javascript. 
Tried doing it like this:

```
 $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Hamburg&rpp=5&lang=all',       function(standings) {
        menStandings.append(standings);
        alert('Done!');
    });
```

All I want to do is to store it in an array called menStandings{} however I get an error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Hamburg&rpp=5&lang=all. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: i see none of the questions you've asked have ever been marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get this working you can use jsonp, you'd have to do something like:

```
$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Hamburg&rpp=5&lang=all&callback=?', function(standings) {
        menStandings.append(standings);
        alert('Done!');
    });
```

where you have a callback=? jquery will fill in the ? with the correct function name and wire things up for you.

you can see an example of this at http://jsfiddle.net/BJq6g/1/

Comment: using JSONP is discouraged...it might be just a simple https calling http dude, in which case he just needs to add an 's' to the end of his link protocol...i.e. https://

Answer (score 1):

This means you're on a different domain (which you are) and you're trying to access another domain and it is getting blocked (cross domain issues).

Many times this happens when you're on an **https** which normally doesn't allow to make request to a different domain as **http**.

Either way your can either verify you're **running from the same protocol**, or use **[JSONP (JSON with Padding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)** in which you're sending a callback to the server that will return the data to you (not recommended but here is an example )
http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

```
$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?_=' + (new Date()).getSeconds() + '&q=Hamburg&rpp=5&lang=all&callback=?', function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

// notes:
//_ + getSeconds - puts a timestamp to ensure no caching.
//callback=? - jquery will put the callback for you so the remote server can respond.
```

However please note that twitter discourage the use of JSONP (and so do I)

> How do I use the REST API over JSON-P?
>
> The REST API supports a callback parameter on nearly all methods. See Things Every Developer Should Know for more information.
>
> In API v1.1 all requests require authentication. Because of this, most JSON-P use cases are actively discouraged as it is rarely
>   possible to perform without exposing your client credentials.

*https://dev.twitter.com/docs/things-every-developer-should-know#jsonp